# Dealing with interdependent files in graph-parallel computation

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, dask, dask-delayed

I’m trying to parallelize the following code ([MCVE](https://pastebin.com/VHcCfvFt)) by creating a task graph using `dask.delayed` (or by [implementing a computational graph](https://www.deepideas.net/deep-learning-from-scratch-i-computational-graphs/) myself):

```
os.chdir('./kitchen1')
write_dough()   # writes file ./dough
write_topping() # writes file ./topping
write_pizza()   # requires ./dough and ./topping; writes ./pizza
```

I see 2 difficulties:

1. `write_dough` doesn't return anything. `z=x+y` makes the dependency between variables clear; this doesn't. [Dask doesn’t recommend relying on side effects](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-rely-on-side-effects). Is there an idiomatic solution?
2. `os.chdir`. How do I incorporate it into a computation graph?
3. I am not concerned about parallelizing file IO, performance, etc.

Here’s my current solution. It adds complexity, and `'./kitchen1'` is everywhere, which is ugly. What would an elegant solution be?

```
write_dough, write_topping, write_pizza = map(dask.delayed, (write_dough, write_topping, write_pizza))

dough = write_dough('./kitchen1')
topping = write_topping('./kitchen1')
pizza = write_pizza(dough, topping, './kitchen1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend your current approach of passing through dependencies explicitly.